# Jekyll includes and YAML frontmatter

Tags: include, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

Is it possible to offload frontmatter to an include in some manner? My Jekyll site uses a frontmatter variable for the page title, however I have some pages that share an include due to code repetition. Putting the frontmatter for the page title in the include treats it like raw HTML. Is there a way to simulate this and set variables in an include?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Jekyll docs on [passing parameter variables to includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameter-variables-to-includes), you need to capture your front-matter as a variable first.

Their example uses capture, but you can use assign if you're just passing the variable through. Here's my tested example of how to do this:

**include**

```
<div>
{{ include.title }} 
</div>
```

**include in content**

```
{% assign include-title = page.title %}
{% include example.html title=include-title %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no front matter in includes.

But you can reach page's title from inside an include by using `page.title`, and any other page's variable with `page.myVarName`.

Comment: Apologies for confusion in the question. I know that frontmatter doesn't work in includes, and I know variables cannot be changed once they are set. Is there a workaround to declare the page title variable inside the include? Essentially, I want the page title to come from the data file that is used in the include.

Comment: So, you can edit your question and explain a little more. Give us some small code samples of what you've already tried.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a parameter to an include. Try:

```
{% include name.html var={{page.title}} %}
```

Then in the include, access the parameter using `include.var`.

See "Pass Parameters to Includes" at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

Comment: Passing parameters to includes is powerful and would likely work for what you're trying to do. On the includes page, see this section in particular: [Passing parameters to includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameters-to-includes).

Comment: this is incorrect and will result in an error. You must turn the front matter into a variable via the assign or capture method., then pass through to the include. I have detailed this method in my answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55616695/3411192